# Cannot register service in Eureka using Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to write something using microservices architecture.
I've created Dockerfiles for each of my Service. Let's assume that I have only 2 microservices right now: Eureka and Gateway. I'm trying to register Gateway service in Eureka.

Here are properties of Gateway:

```
server:
  port: 8000
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    multiplications:
      path: /multiplications/**
      serviceId: multiplication
      strip-prefix: false
    results:
      path: /results/**
      serviceId: multiplication
      strip-prefix: false
    leaders:
      path: /leaders/**
      serviceId: gamification
      strip-prefix: false

endpoints:
  trace:
    sensitive: false

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
     default-zone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/
```

Here are properties of Eureka:

```
server:
  port: 8761
```

I'm using Docker compose for my containers. Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
        service-registry:
                        build:
                                context: service-registry
                        image: service-registry:latest
                        ports:
                          - "8761:8761"
                        networks:
                                - backend
        gateway:
                        build:
                                context: gateway
                        image: gateway:latest
                        depends_on:
                                - service-registry
                        ports:
                          - "8000:8000"
                        networks:
                                - backend
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is exception from logs:

**com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server**

I don't know what to do with this. I've tried change the eureka host to localhost, but it does not work.

Comment: Anyone? I don't have any idea.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you solved it? I realized that eureka is exposing in docker container as a http://localhost:8761 there is no /eureka/ path after domain, other services try to register over http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Answer (score -1):

Similar issue posted in [Applications not registering to eureka when using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266795/applications-not-registering-to-eureka-when-using-docker-compose)

Solution - change default-zone to defaultZone keyword in gateway configuration. It's helped me while I tried run my services in docker's containers.

I've no idea why this works like that - if someone has some information please write answer below...